# Inequivalent holomorphic atlases

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, differential-topology, projective-geometry, kahler-manifolds

What is an example of a differential manifold which possesses two holomorphic atlases which are equivalent as differential atlases but inequivalent as holomorphic atlases? Moreover, for this example, are these nice  properties distinguishing each atlas?

Comment: The manifold $\mathbb{R}^2$ has a unique smooth structure but two distinct complex structures: $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{D}$. The holomorphic atlases associated to $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{D}$ satisfy the requirements you're looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In dimensions smaller than 4, there is only one differential structure for each topological manifold. That was proved by Tibor Radó for dimension $1$ and $2$, and by Edwin E. Moise in dimension $3$.

Now take $T_g$, the connected sum of $g$ tori: this is a smooth topological surface of genus $g$, hence there is a unique smooth structure on it. By contrast, if $g \ge 2$ then the complex structures on $T_g$ (up to the action of homeomorphisms that are isotopic to the identity) form a space of real dimension $6g-6$, see Teichmuller theory.